# How can I change the border color of an event in Vuetify Calendar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have tried picking up the class after inspecting the element and then adding it to my Sass stylesheet, but it doesn't work that way. Made the values !important and removed scoped too and it still is not working.
Any suggestions on how to get it to work ?

[image: screenshot of the calendar I am working on]

On inspecting the element, this is the class: .theme--dark.v-calendar-events .v-event-timed

[image: .theme--dark.v-calendar-events .v-event-timed]

If I add the border style inside inspect element of the above class. It works fine. But it doesn't in my project.

Comment: you can try this in your scoped style 
`/deep/ .theme--dark.v-calender-events .v-event-timed { border ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add div selector before the vuetify CSS selector.

[Example taken from Vuetify Calendar page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars/#drag-and-drop)

```css
div .theme--light.v-calendar-events .v-event-timed {
  border: 5px solid brown !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-row class="fill-height">
    <v-col>
      <v-sheet height="600">
        <v-calendar
          ref="calendar"
          v-model="value"
          color="primary"
          type="4day"
          :events="events"
          :event-color="getEventColor"
          :event-ripple="false"
          @change="getEvents"
          @mousedown:event="startDrag"
          @mousedown:time="startTime"
          @mousemove:time="mouseMove"
          @mouseup:time="endDrag"
          @mouseleave.native="cancelDrag"
        >
          <template v-slot:event="{ event, timed, eventSummary }">
            <div
              class="v-event-draggable"
              v-html="eventSummary()"
            ></div>
            <div
              v-if="timed"
              class="v-event-drag-bottom"
              @mousedown.stop="extendBottom(event)"
            ></div>
          </template>
        </v-calendar>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: () => ({
      value: '',
      events: [],
      colors: ['#2196F3', '#3F51B5', '#673AB7', '#00BCD4', '#4CAF50', '#FF9800', '#757575'],
      names: ['Meeting', 'Holiday', 'PTO', 'Travel', 'Event', 'Birthday', 'Conference', 'Party'],
      dragEvent: null,
      dragStart: null,
      createEvent: null,
      createStart: null,
      extendOriginal: null,
    }),
    methods: {
      startDrag ({ event, timed }) {
        if (event && timed) {
          this.dragEvent = event
          this.dragTime = null
          this.extendOriginal = null
        }
      },
      startTime (tms) {
        const mouse = this.toTime(tms)

        if (this.dragEvent && this.dragTime === null) {
          const start = this.dragEvent.start

          this.dragTime = mouse - start
        } else {
          this.createStart = this.roundTime(mouse)
          this.createEvent = {
            name: `Event #${this.events.length}`,
            color: this.rndElement(this.colors),
            start: this.createStart,
            end: this.createStart,
            timed: true,
          }

          this.events.push(this.createEvent)
        }
      },
      extendBottom (event) {
        this.createEvent = event
        this.createStart = event.start
        this.extendOriginal = event.end
      },
      mouseMove (tms) {
        const mouse = this.toTime(tms)

        if (this.dragEvent && this.dragTime !== null) {
          const start = this.dragEvent.start
          const end = this.dragEvent.end
          const duration = end - start
          const newStartTime = mouse - this.dragTime
          const newStart = this.roundTime(newStartTime)
          const newEnd = newStart + duration

          this.dragEvent.start = newStart
          this.dragEvent.end = newEnd
        } else if (this.createEvent && this.createStart !== null) {
          const mouseRounded = this.roundTime(mouse, false)
          const min = Math.min(mouseRounded, this.createStart)
          const max = Math.max(mouseRounded, this.createStart)

          this.createEvent.start = min
          this.createEvent.end = max
        }
      },
      endDrag () {
        this.dragTime = null
        this.dragEvent = null
        this.createEvent = null
        this.createStart = null
        this.extendOriginal = null
      },
      cancelDrag () {
        if (this.createEvent) {
          if (this.extendOriginal) {
            this.createEvent.end = this.extendOriginal
          } else {
            const i = this.events.indexOf(this.createEvent)
            if (i !== -1) {
              this.events.splice(i, 1)
            }
          }
        }

        this.createEvent = null
        this.createStart = null
        this.dragTime = null
        this.dragEvent = null
      },
      roundTime (time, down = true) {
        const roundTo = 15 // minutes
        const roundDownTime = roundTo * 60 * 1000

        return down
          ? time - time % roundDownTime
          : time + (roundDownTime - (time % roundDownTime))
      },
      toTime (tms) {
        return new Date(tms.year, tms.month - 1, tms.day, tms.hour, tms.minute).getTime()
      },
      getEventColor (event) {
        const rgb = parseInt(event.color.substring(1), 16)
        const r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF
        const g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF
        const b = (rgb >> 0) & 0xFF

        return event === this.dragEvent
          ? `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, 0.7)`
          : event === this.createEvent
            ? `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, 0.7)`
            : event.color
      },
      getEvents ({ start, end }) {
        const events = []

        const min = new Date(`${start.date}T00:00:00`).getTime()
        const max = new Date(`${end.date}T23:59:59`).getTime()
        const days = (max - min) / 86400000
        const eventCount = this.rnd(days, days + 20)

        for (let i = 0; i < eventCount; i++) {
          const timed = this.rnd(0, 3) !== 0
          const firstTimestamp = this.rnd(min, max)
          const secondTimestamp = this.rnd(2, timed ? 8 : 288) * 900000
          const start = firstTimestamp - (firstTimestamp % 900000)
          const end = start + secondTimestamp

          events.push({
            name: this.rndElement(this.names),
            color: this.rndElement(this.colors),
            start,
            end,
            timed,
          })
        }

        this.events = events
      },
      rnd (a, b) {
        return Math.floor((b - a + 1) * Math.random()) + a
      },
      rndElement (arr) {
        return arr[this.rnd(0, arr.length - 1)]
      },
    },
  
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't do it without an important? Always prefer to find a way without it if it's doable.

Comment: Since Vuetify already has set css stylings, the best way to override these is with the !important add on.

Comment: Vuetify uses important to set it? If not, your css may just override it. But if you say it's doable only this way, all right.

Comment: There are very few things that work without !important, when speaking about overriding vuetify styling. I had to remove scoped as well so that I could access the vuetify css and override them to a good extent. I know its not the best practice But it works for now.